# Prove $\|u + v\|_\infty \le \|u\|_\infty + \|v\|_\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Is it enough to say that

$$\max(|u_1 + v_1|, \ldots, |u_n+ v_n|) \le \max |u_1, \ldots, u_n| + \max |v_1, \ldots, v_n|$$

by triangle inequality?

Comment: How I would approach it is that the LHS is going to be equal to $|u_i+v_i|$ for some $i$. Apply triangle inequality to this, then see if you can get it from there.

Comment: Something like $\max |u_i + v_i| \le \max |u_i| + \max |v_i|$?

Comment: You got it. $\,\,$

Comment: Thank you, Cameron Williams.